# Email Comparisons with Count Data ANOVA

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons

I have 4 different emails each with different subject lines. My goal is to determine if the difference in the open rate is due to random chance or subject line.

My emails were sent out in parallel at the same time, to a randomized audience.

I first tried to use ANOVA tests but quickly found out ANOVA is better used for comparing means and not comparing simple counts. I know i'll have to deal with a potential FDR. I'm just looking for help in which direction I should proceed. It seems to me that this could be a binomial distribution (customer opened email [1] or didn't[0]) but am not sure if this is correct. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sms
import math

#email open and delivered by version
ea_opens=300
ea_del=1500
eb_opens=250
eb_del=1500
ec_opens=400
ec_del=1500
ed_opens=500
ed_del=1500
alpha=.05**4

#email arrays
email_a=np.hstack(([0]*(ea_del-ea_opens),[1]*ea_opens)).astype(int)
email_b=np.hstack(([0]*(eb_del-eb_opens),[1]*eb_opens)).astype(int)
email_c=np.hstack(([0]*(ec_del-ec_opens),[1]*ec_opens)).astype(int)
email_d=np.hstack(([0]*(ed_del-ed_opens),[1]*ed_opens)).astype(int)
```

Comment: I see that you have set this up with Python, but [here](http://www.marketingdistillery.com/2014/08/10/multiple-abn-tests-in-marketing-with-anova-and-r/) is an example of how you might go about doing this in R.

Comment: Sounds like a $2\times k$ homogeneity of proportions (with $k=4$), so conventionally something like a chi-squared test unless you have other covariates.

Comment: @Glen_b, would [Tukey's HSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test#Advantages_and_disadvantages) or similar not be appropriate here?

Comment: The usual assumptions of ANOVA don't really hold, though for a one-way ANOVA with large samples and proportions not too close to either bound it's less of an issue (since then under the null the variance should be constant, the discreteness shouldn't bite you too hard and the skewness shouldn't have too much impact). If the approximation is good enough to do ANOVA, HSD is probably about as good as at any other time, aside from the issue of heteroskedasticity under the alternative; beyond that I'm not aware of any specific issue relating to HSD